# Ahk script failing randomly. How can i optimaze my code?

Tags: autohotkey

Why is my ahk script failing randomly after working well for a while? How can I optimize my script to never fail? Often it fails in 3D games while I am trying to move my camera to the other side or something like that.

```
MouseClick, left, -325, 125, 1, 0, D, R ;
MouseClick, left, 0, 0, 1, 0, U, R ;
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't speak as to why your script is failing (I would encourage you to provide more detail if possible), it appears that you're trying to drag from -325,125 to 0,0. In this case, I would recommend using `MouseClickDrag` instead.

```
MouseClickDrag , Left , -325 , 125 , 0 , 0
```